# comparing list and print

Tags: python

```
arr = ["mincraft", "Star"]
inputs = ["minecraft?s update", "StarWars", "Babe"]
i = 0
while i != len(inputs):
    if any(words in inputs[i] for words in arr):
        print inputs[i];
    i += 1
```

This code outputs `Starwars`, how do I make it so that the string from `arr` (`Star`) will be printed instead of the string in inputs (`StarWars`).

Comment: `print arr[1]` and it will print "Star" from `arr`

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal hahaha,,idk if that was a joke but it made me laugh. :D

Comment: lol it was partially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = ["mincraft","Star"]
inputs = ["minecraft?s update","StarWars","Babe"]

for item in arr:
    if len([x for x in inputs if item in x]) > 0: print item
```

Output: `Star`

Comment: Thanks,,and it also makes the code smaller and clean

Answer (score 4):

You can do this :

```
temp = [i for i in arr for j in inputs if i in j]
```

Output :

```
['Star']
```